# Load Balancing , Purely Redirect

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, centos, load-balancing

I was reading up on Load balancing today. From what i know, Rackspace Load Balancing would handle all data. The question i have with me is, why cant the load balancer just redirect connections? Instead , it is handling all the connection, it feels like a bottleneck because One is trying to scale but at the same time it has to go through the load balancer, all the data.

I read that , the session would be lost. Is there anyway for it to just redirect only? Different server has different IP but public has access to one only ... hmmm , I know that session is store in server... Not DB.

So It just has to be that all data just has to go through Load balancer? It's like paying for Outgoing Charges for Server + Load Balancing. Data sort of doubld in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a theoretical one, so it doesn't really fits SO

But to answer your question, the Load Balancer has to have the user reach the same server all the time otherwise the session information may not be maintained. Think of it this way, your PHP application on Server A issues a session, the same PHP application on Server B doesn't know about this session unless you are syncing the session information between the two servers.

If you are just offering static information, that you aren't looking for a Load Balancer, but rather a CDN (Content delivery network), and CDN doesn't need to do anything like what you described, it can redirect you to any available server.